# Installed Blu Ray drive, now regular DVD drive is messed up

Tags: drivers, dvd, compact-disc, media, blu-ray

I installed an LG Blu Ray drive. This drive only works reliably with the software with which it came ("CyberLink Mediasuite / PowerDVD"). Using, say WinDVD, results in wierd errors.

My real problem though is that my regular DVD drive, an old Sony is now messed up ever since I installed the Blu Ray. Doing anything with it takes an INCREDIBLY long time, like 5 minutes to copy a 60 megabyte file off the drive. Just clicking on a file on the CD in Windows File Manager causes a delay of over 60 seconds.

What can I do to restore my regular DVD drive to the way it was?

PS Using Windows XP

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try out here.

1. Make sure all the mobo drivers for your sata/ide ports are up to date.  Simple...but always start with easy.
2. Make sure no other optical drive programs are running when trying to use one or the other, they could be conflicting.
3. As the Blu Ray drive should cover everything consider removing the old DVD drive (is the BRD read only?)
4. Consider upgrading to Win7.  I was having issues with newer components on WinXP and a friend said "Seriously just update to Win7" which I was reluctant to do of course and things worked well after I did.  You can get upgrade versions of Win7 pretty cheap.